# ImageResizer license in staging or development environment

Tags: c#, .net, imageresizer

We are using a ImageResizer Performance License and it seems that the map with our developpement environment is not working :

```
1 Issues detected:

resizer configuration(ConfigurationError):  You can only map non-public hostnames to arbitrary licenses. Skipping bruneaumedia.dev1fr.isg.jm-bruneau.com
```

bruneaumedia.dev1fr.isg.jm-bruneau.com is a private domain but considered as public. We have other development environment but none is considered as private.

Is there something we are missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Full outpout from resizer.debug :

```
Image resizer diagnostic sheet      bruneaumedia.dev1fr.isg.jm-bruneau.com  26/01/2016 12:44:19

1 Issues detected:

resizer configuration(ConfigurationError):  You can only map non-public hostnames to arbitrary licenses. Skipping bruneaumedia.dev1fr.isg.jm-bruneau.com


Assembly use report: 


You are using plugins and assemblies from the V4 Performance Edition.

----------------

License keys

List of installed domain licenses:
bruneaumedia.fr => R4Performance

----------------

Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.WebConfigLicenseReader
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.LicenseVerifier.LicenseEnforcer`1[ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache]
ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs.PrettyGifs
ImageResizer.Plugins.ImageDownloader.ImageDownloaderPlugin

Configuration:

<resizer>
<diagnostics enableFor="localhost" />
<licenses>
<maphost from="bruneaumedia.dev1fr.isg.jm-bruneau.com" to="bruneaumedia.fr" />
<license>RG9t...</license>
</licenses>
<clientcache minutes="1440" />
<plugins>
<add name="DiskCache" />
<add name="PrettyGifs" />
<add name="ImageDownloader" />
</plugins>
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, colors, dither, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, crop, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, dpi, zoom, autorotate, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi,
```

Comment: This seems like a licensing issue. My guess is that it would be better to contact support directly: support@imageresizing.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a private subdomain of `bruneaumedia.fr` or add a license for `jm-bruneau.com`

ImageResizer only permits .local subdomains and single-hostname (like `testserver`) usage for free via mapping.

And, you can, of course use any subdomain of your purchased domain for free. The latter is a common approach, as you can control access in a variety of ways (private DNS record, private IP, IP whitelisting, IIS authentication, etc).

In this instance you are trying to use ImageResizer against a different hostname than the one you purchased. ImageResizer cannot validate the public/private nature of a hostname, only whether it has the *potential* to work on public DNS.

Answer (score 0):

We are using a ImageResizer Performance License, and we use different subdomain .local for development, Staging.
The Image resizer diagnostic sheet gives the same result than Ludovic Martin:

```
2 Issues detected:

resizer configuration(ConfigurationError):  You can only map non-public hostnames to arbitrary licenses. Skipping media.staging.private-domain.local


resizer configuration(ConfigurationError):  You can only map non-public hostnames to arbitrary licenses. Skipping media.dev.private-domain.local
```

config file :

```
<licenses>
      <maphost from="media.staging.private-domain.local" to="public-domain.fr" />
      <maphost from="media.dev.private-domain.local" to="public-domain.fr" />
      <license>
        RG9t...
      </license>
</licenses>
```

Comment: It seems that the public domain works.
But no domain in *.local, section maphost seems not work. I followed the documentation http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/install/license_keys